# Windows to ios files for Unity?

Tags: android, ios, unity-game-engine

i currently make android apps, so im thinking about buying unity3d so i can develop for android and ios with the same project so i have a couple of questions:

1. i have the free version now, so if i develop a game with it, can i use the same project when i purchase the licences?
2. i am using windows and the free version says that i cannot export an ios version of the app im making on windows, so if i get an apple computer will unity open a project that i have made on a windows computer?

thank you for your time :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> i have the free version now, so if i develop a game with it, can i use
>   the same project when i purchase the licences?

Yes you can. Btw now iOS and Android licenses are free. So you can already deploy on those devices for free.

> am using windows and the free version says that i cannot export an ios
>   version of the app im making on windows, so if i get an apple computer
>   will unity open a project that i have made on a windows computer?

Yes you can. Unfurtunately you can't deploy on iOS devices from Windows, since Unity3D export an XCode project and you must have OSX to build it.

Answer (score -1):

I was browsing the net for the same issue i.e, building xcode on Windows using unity and came across the below link.

http://techexxpert.blogspot.in/2011/06/developing-iphone-games-with-unity-on.html

Hope it works!!

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.